# CCS MSP430 Bluetopia Linker

Tags: c, bluetooth, msp430, code-composer

I am trying to implement the Bluetopia stack using the MSP430F5635 MCU and the CC256 bluetooth chip using Code Composer v7. When I try to build my project, I am getting the error: "unresolved symbol BSC_Initialize ...". I have the BSCAPI header file included so I can't figure out why it cannot find this function.

Below is the relevant code I am using:

```
#include "BSCAPI.h"
...
int main(void) {
    ...
    Result = BSC_Initialize(&HCI_DriverInformation, 0);
    ...
}
```

Comment: "unresolved symbol BSC_Initialize ..." could be a link error. Have you included BSC library in link? If you just compile the file, do you see any error?

Comment: Yes, the BSC_Initialize function is declared in the BSCAPI header like this: `BTPSAPI_DECLARATION int BTPSAPI BSC_Initialize(HCI_DriverInformation_t *HCI_DriverInformation, unsigned long Flags);`

Comment: Well, it's not about the header file, can you check if the library file, e.g. BSCSDK.lib, is added to the link.

Comment: Looks like that was the problem, thanks for the help!